# How to make urls with a for loop in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

demo:

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

In this demo above,`urls` are written manually in `start_requests()` method,if there are 50 pages,the urls are like this:

```
http://www.example.com/page/1
http://www.example.com/page/2
...
...
http://www.example.com/page/50
```

How to make these urls with a for loop?

Answer (score 3):

```
 urls = ('http://www.example.com/page/{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,51))
```

The variable `urls` will be used in a for loop, thus, it can be a generator or container.
You can use list, tuple, or generator.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a list of urls 1..50, try this

```
urls = ['http://www.example.com/page/' + str(i) for i in range(1, 51)]
```

You have the same characters at the start and just want to convert the numbers in `range(1,51)` to strings and append then.